# Why is it impossible for program contents to be modified by the program itself in case of Harvard architecture?

Tags: computer-architecture

In the below link , it is mentioned that in case of Harvard Architecture it is impossible for the program memory to modify its contents so how can it happen  since instructions are fetched from the Program Memory only , and there will be instructions to modify  contents pertaining to that data only so how can it happen that the program cannot modify its own contents ?

http://spiroprojects.com/blog/cat-view-more.php?blogname=Difference-Between-Von-Neumann-Architecture-and-Harvard-Architecture&id=130

Comment: You answered it yourself. There are no instructions that can modify the memory containing the program.

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand it clearly.